# Adding new fields into Device Admin Page (OpenGTS-v2.5.9)

Tags: java, opengts

I am using OpenGTS-v2.5.9. I wanted to add some new fields into device admin page (web interface), I have tried adding the code in `DeviceInfo.java` but when I recompile and deploy I dont find those new fields added to device admin page. So please guide me in obtaining the new fields on the device admin page, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to see any changes made ​​in the source code :

- Stop Tomcat.
- clean the destination.
- clean build.
- compile
- deploy
- start Tomcat

`service tomcat stop
 rm -R $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/track
 rm -R $GTS_HOME/build/
 ant clean
 ant all track track.deploy
 service tomcat start`

Comment: I have been doing all the above mentioned steps. I have problem in making newly added fields to display on Device Admin page. I have made necessary changes in code in DeviceInfo.java file to display the new fields  on device admin page, yet it fails. So my question is am I making changes in  the right file or missing out some major points to be considered in adding custom fields for device admin page in opengts.